# Simple calculated property and DTO

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I have a WCF service which exposes its interface with DTOs. I have an entity class `MyClass` which has two properties `SimpleProperty1` and `SimpleProperty2`. There is a calculated property in this class named `CalculatedProperty1` which uses the above two properties in calculating its value. I have a `MyClassDTO` dto class which has only the two simple properties.
In the UI, where a `MyClassDTO` object is being modified, I want the user to see the value of `CalculatedProperty` on the fly. However, as according to my understanding DTOs should not have any logic embedded in them. And it seems a bit of a waste to implement a function in the web service to get the calculated value of the property in such a simple scenario. How should I go about getting this done? What are the standard approaches of doing this? I see that the generated classes from the WCF service are defined as partial classes. Is it there to handle this sort of scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use extension method to show the calculated property

```
 public class MyClassDTO
{
    public string P1 { get; set; }

    public string P2 { get; set; }
}

public static class MyClassDtoExtension
{
    public static string ToCalculatedProperty(this MyClassDTO obj)
    {
        return obj.P1 + obj.P2;
    }
}
```

// usage

```
        var d = new MyClassDTO(){P1 = "1",P2 = "2"};

        d.ToCalculatedProperty();
```

Comment: I need a property for data binding.

Comment: you can use it as data binding property also. Post your biding code , how your are binding